# Implementing Docusign ESignature REST API Authentication

Tags: javascript, docusignapi

Used case

We have a web application developed using HTML5, Javascript, and CSS3 from which we want to sign a sales contract pdf from the end customer. It’s a responsive web application which can be used from desktop/laptop, tablet or mobile phones. We intend to use the e-signature REST API directly without using any SDK.

E-Signature possible in two ways:

1. Sales representative is face-to-face with the customer, shows the contract to the customer on his (sales representative’s) device and the customer signs. [Will be the most use method as it’s a high value sale].
2. Send an e-mail to customer to sign the contract. [Used in exceptional cases]

Questions/Requests

1. What is the appropriate authentication method to be used in this case?

**Note -** The sales person who will be getting the document sign to have a docusign account.
preferably it should not be mandatory as in our case as sales person is a third party partner.

2. Is it mandatory for the end customer, who will be signing the document to have a DocuSign account? If NO, then how does this technically work.

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You may want to use JWT since your end user doesn't have DocuSign credentials.
2. No, the signer doesn't have to have a DocuSign account, but they have to be identified somehow, name+email or name+phone number information should be provided.

Comment: In first method-
We are not sure how secure in the first method as we don't have electronic evidence of the customer that signed by the end customer. Kindly suggest me.  Thanks.

Comment: This is very secure. You can do more to secure things. You can, for example, request SMS authentication so customer gets a code on their mobile device to make it more secure.

Comment: Very important to keep the RSA private key safe, not share it or have it on an unsecure server.